# Create a texture from a sample

Tags: image-generation

Photoshop has a great feature - Fill/Content-Aware. That's what it does. You have an image with more or less uniform content (ideally a pattern) and you want to expand that content over a larger area. To do this you create free space and use this tool. It sounds cool, but unfortunately this tool does not always give an acceptable result. I'm looking for a tool that performs a similar task, but in a smarter way.

Ideally, this should be a tool that creates a seamless texture based on the sample. Of the ready-made solutions, I found Withpoly, but I cannot highly appreciate the result of this work. Also while searching I came across this post:
[Using AI to extend an imagine pattern](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/37222/using-ai-to-extend-an-imagine-pattern/37223#37223).
The first answer is almost what I need, but I'm not familiar with Torch (just a little Keras) and I can't change the code so that the result is like in the answer (seamless texture).

Please advise an app (online or local. and of course I'm looking for a free app), or a ready-made Keras solution for solving such a problem.